# How to tell if worming medication was effective?

Tags: cats, medicines, parasites

Are there any 'clues' to confirm that worming medication has worked and my cat doesn't have worms?

(My cat goes to the toilet outside so I can't check for 'poo-clues', if that even is a way :D )

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try getting yourself a litter box and keeping the cat indoors until you've verified the cat no longer has any worms in their stool.  This way you can be completely sure that the cat is free of them.  Otherwise it will be extremely hard to monitor.

Comment: Do you think it is ok to worm her within a month or so of the last worming?

Answer (score 1):

Only laboratory test can tell you 100% truth. Take her/his dirty to a vet. 
Test will shoow whether there are worms or their eggs or not. Some kinds of worms are too small so you are not able to see it.